# Two htaccess files in control of one website

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I go to

```
www.mydomain.tld/sk/
```

everything works fine, link is not changed.
But when I delete forward slash

```
www.mydomain.tld/sk
```

the page is changed to

```
www.mydomain.tld/domains/mydomain.tld/sk/?lang=sk
```

Can anybody help please? How can avoid the link to be changed?
When I go to www.mydomain.tld/sk I need it to remain the same.

**.htaccess file (1)**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^sk$ /index.php?lang=sk [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^sk/$ /index.php?lang=sk [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^sk/index /index.php?lang=sk [L,QSA]
```

There is another one **.htaccess file (2)** in the top main directory
and it contains these lines

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^domains/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) domains/%2/$1 [DPI,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^domains/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]
Options -indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This .htaccess file helps to navigate domains that I am running at server.
All web sites are in a directory /domains . 
So for example www.mydomain.tld is pointing to /domains/mydomain.tld directory. 
In this directory is the shorter htaccess file (1).

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy, but I think it's because in .htaccess file (1) your link are from the root, and are not at root...

Try with: .htaccess file (1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^sk/?$ index.php?lang=sk [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^sk/index index.php?lang=sk [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It did not help. Link www.mydomain.tld/sk still rewrites to www.mydomain.tld/domains/mydomain.tld/sk/?lang=sk

Comment: Just for one test, can you try to delete 2 lines in file 2: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^domains/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]`

Comment: No effect. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Are you sure, it's not because the result is cached ? You should do your testing with [R=302]

Answer (score -1):

look at

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^domains/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/
```

here are you testing if REQUEST_URI does not start with "**domains**" OR "**/domains**"
however in the previous htaccess, you guarantee that REQUEST_URI will start with **www**

you probably want REQUEST_FILENAME instead of REQUEST_URI here

Comment: `you guarantee that REQUEST_URI will start with www` this is incorrect you're misreading his rules. what he is guaranteeing is that the DOMAIN will start with `www` not the path after the domain. `REQUEST_URI` contains everything after the domain name for example `www.domain.com/test`, the `REQUEST_URI` will be `/test`.

Answer (score -1):

I spent many hours by trying to solve it in htaccess, but nothing work. 
So i just 301 redirect the wrong link in php:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=="/domains/mydomain.tld/sk/?lang=sk") {
  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
  header("Location: http://www.mydomain.tld/sk/");
  exit();
}
```